# x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, 64-bit, gcc, mingw32

I have 64bit ubuntu virtual machine and a 64bit binary still getting the Exec format error.

```
$ lsb_release -a    
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty   

$ uname -a    
Linux shrikant-VirtualBox 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux   

$ file ../Mingw_instatllation/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++     
../Mingw_instatllation/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable    

$ ../Mingw_instatllation/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ test.cpp    
bash: ../Mingw_instatllation/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Can someone either point me to a good mingw tool chain or give suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The [`Mach-O`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) executable format is not used or supported in Ubuntu. The standard executable format for Ubuntu (and Linux in general) is [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

Install the [`mingw32`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mingw32) package:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw32
```

(Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986715/mingw-cross-compiling-on-linux).)